# Getting differences between WVGA800 and WVGA854 in Android Emulator

Tags: android

So far I just have one XML layout file, and one drawable directory, drawable-hdpi. 
I first want to target the high density screens.

I added a bunch of imagebuttons to a relativelayout and everything looks perfect in the WVGA800 emulator. The problem arises when I view it in the WVGA854 emulator. Not only do the imagebuttons not position the same, but the images are blurry. I used dip for the layout margins on the imagebuttons even though it shouldn't matter in this case because WVGA800 and 854 are both high density. What is the problem? Why would it look totally different on emulators that have the same density and almost have the same exact screen dimensions?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds odd. Screenshots / XML might help.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, closing/restarting Eclipse and the Emulator worked. Sorry for the stupid question.